# Internet Time tab has disappeared from the Date and Time applet of the Control Panel

Tags: windows-7, date-time

Previously, there was an **Internet Time** tab on the **Date and Time** applet of the Control Panel, wherein one could force a query of an internet time server and also type in a different server from the ones supplied. However, this tab has now disappeared, and I need to have it back. I should mention that this machine has never been part of a domain, since it seems that machines that are such do not have such a tab. I should be obliged to anyone who can help me restore the missing tab.

Windows 7 Home Premium
Service Pack 1

Comment: I have a dumb question: what happens if you click on the "Change date and time" button on the dialogue box?

Comment: You get a dialogue box called **Date and Time Settings**, whcih allows one to change, manually, the date and time, but nothing  that allows one to configure the Windows service that automatically queries internet time servers or to force a query. _That_ was accessed by a tab on the main **Date and Time** dialogue box, now gone missing.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still am, despite having tried the suggedtions kindly offered by Caleb Anderson.

Comment: Do you have Windows Time enabled in the services.msc?

Comment: Yes, Windows Time is enabled and running.

Answer (score 23):

It sounds like the computer thinks it is part of a Domain.  As you mentioned the internet time tab is disabled for domain environments.  The computer will sync with the domain controller and there isn't a way to have it sync to the internet in domains.

I think this article from Microsoft might help.  It provides a number of registry values that effect this area.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042

Also, you might be able to run a few commands from command prompt to resolve this too:

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:MANUAL /manualpeerlist:time.nist.gov
w32tm /config /update
```

Comment: He specifically says: `I should mention that this machine has never been part of a domain, since it seems that machines that are such do not have such a tab.`

Comment: I totally missed that.  I edited my post to hopefully provide a better answer.  Thanks for directing me to my oversight.

Answer (score 7):

If your computer is not a domain member, the Windows Time service can be set to Manual startup mode and should ordinarily **not** be running.

Try just stopping the service to see if the additional tab returns. You may have to go as far as setting it to Manual startup and rebooting.

---

Additionally, the registry key `HKEY\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers` needs to be configured correctly in order to make it work. In the screen shot below, there are six available time servers listed, but the **(Default)** value is empty.

[image: time server key (misconfigured)]

The **(Default)** value needs to have something in it. Otherwise, the Internet Time tab will not show. Specifically, the **(Default)** value needs to have the name of one of the other values in this **Servers** key. It cannot have an invalid value. Using the screen shot again, a value of 6 would be invalid, because there is no corresponding time server labelled "6." On my machine, the **(Default)** value is 1, which means my computer gets time from time.windows.com.

Comment: Stopped it, set it to Manual and rebooted: no luck—still no Internet Time tab.

Comment: Did you check the additional registry-related info I posted?

Comment: **Just did it about 15 minutes ago. There was no (Default) value set. Now Windows syncs time both automatically and manually, once I removed the no longer operational time servers. Thanks to everyone for the help.**

Comment: There are still some mysteries left. On my computer the time-server according to the Internet Time tab is time-nw.nist.gov, but (Default) is "1" ([link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DQvyw.jpg)), which according to you should mean time.windows.com. I conjecture that (Default) should be non-empty for historical reasons, but that Windows 7 picks randomly a server, maybe only checking that it really works.

Comment: I get what you're saying. Maybe Windows starts with the value you put in (Default) but could change servers for a number of reasons. I know when I was putting different numbers in for the (Default) value, the time server name changed appropriately in the Date/Time applet. Like a lot of things in Windows, we may never know every detail of how it works.  I also wonder if the actual selected server is based on your location.

Comment: @RobertThornton: "I removed the no longer operational time servers": Are you saying that the real problem was that the contents of the Servers key were loused up? Because of my previous comment I don't really believe in (Default).

Comment: I was trying to disable Internet Time to fix the timezone conflicts between Windows and Linux in dualboot, but no luck, my computer was part of my workplace's domain, so I had no `Internet Time` tab. Thanks to your reply I was able to disable the Internet Time by unsetting the `(Default)` value and it fixed my problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions of Windows, the Internet Time tab was not built-into the Date and Time applet,
but was added there by the Windows Time service. In Windows 7 I found weird things happening,
such as seeing the service running although it was set to Manual, or of seeing Internet Time displayed and time-sync done even when the service is disabled.

I'm starting to think that Windows 7 will start the service when time-sync is to be done,
no matter what is specified as its Startup type. I still don't know whether the Internet Time tab
is now built-in or is still being added there by the service on its first run.

It seems however likely to me that there is still some connection between the service
and the Internet Time tab, so that some corruption caused this mechanism to malfunction.

The Time service is defined in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time`. In case that the problem is caused by registry corruption, I have posted this key's contents [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cuFgRsuj) for comparison. Do not import it blindly into the registry (or at least not before saving yours).

Otherwise, all I can suggest are general troubleshooting steps such as the [System File Checker](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

Comment: Um, [this](http://superuser.com/questions/250547/internet-time-tab-has-disappeared-from-the-date-and-time-applet-of-the-control-p#comment519899_250547) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/250547/internet-time-tab-has-disappeared-from-the-date-and-time-applet-of-the-control-p#comment521376_448362). You should know better.

Comment: @Synetech: It seems to me I am simply not agreeing with the second "this", while saying that the first "this" is correct but might still not work because of registry corruption. I should maybe have been clearer about it, rather than going for a too-general answer.

Comment: You said to make sure the Time Service is running but it has already been established *twice* that he made sure it is.

Comment: @Synetech: That's what I meant by "too general", meaning going beyond the bounds of this post. But the advice to "stopping the service to see if the additional tab returns" is totally mistaken.

Comment: ...I agree that this answer is not the best worded, but it at least passes the message.

Comment: What message? To enable the service? That has already been [established](http://superuser.com/questions/250547/internet-time-tab-has-disappeared-from-the-date-and-time-applet-of-the-control-p/449214#comment521376_448362) to be the case; twice.

Comment: @Synetech: No, to verify the service's registry configuration. And to explain WHY the service must be running.

Comment: The service need not be running. On my domain-joined PC, the service is running and there is no Internet Time tab (makes sense, because I'm in a domain). On my non-domain PC, the service is not running, and I have the tab. It is likely that the service must not be disabled, but the notion that the service must be running is incorrect.

Comment: @PatrickS.: Yes, there is something weird here. I just rechecked and also found Internet Time displayed and the service not running. Previously, I'm absolutely sure that I saw it running even though it was on Manual. I've even disabled it and rebooted, but Internet Time is still displayed and time-sync is on. I'm thinking now that Windows starts the service whenever required for time sync, no matter what's its startup type, and maybe that's also when Internet Time is added. I still believe that Internet Time missing means something is wrong with the service.

Comment: @Synetech: I have rewritten my answer in view of new data.

Comment: It does seem to be a convoluted process, however it works. I have built-in time-related tasks in Task Scheduler (under Microsoft\Windows). I'm not sure what role these play either.  I did verify the registry stuff in my answer on a few PCs, so I know that *could* be the issue. We'll have to see what's actually wrong with Robert's PC. For any future readers, I think several answers should stand, as there are likely many possible culprits.

Comment: @PatrickS.: "time-related tasks" : I found only "Time Synchronization" for 01:00 every sunday. Did you find more ?

Comment: On my domain-joined PC, that's what I have. I don't have the non-domain PC with me at the moment. But the Time Sync task starts the w32time service with an extra argument.

Comment: **@harrymc, there was a considerable difference between your registry key and mine, which you can see at [link](https://sites.google.com/a/robert-thornton.net/internet-time-tab/)—my original key on the left, yours on the right—so I replaced mine with yours. As it happens, though, Patrick S. had the correct answer.**

Comment: It seems like @Patrick S. had the right registry corruption. Does Internet Time still work with your original services\W32Time settings? (Some of the differences looked significant.) If it does then I will delete my answer.

Comment: I cannot tell you if it would've worked under my original registry settings, inasmuch as I left yours in place, intending to revert to my original settings only if necessary, which it wasn't. Even after making the change that Patrick S. suggested, and thereby restoring the missing Internet Time tab in the Date and Time applet, I still could not start w32time, nor was I able to get it to start by manually changing in services.msc the account under which it runs to Local Service. However, unregistering and then registering the service seemed to fix that.

Comment: OK, so I will leave my answer here as another possible corruption point. I wonder how your registry got loused up so much. Did you run a cleaner?

Comment: ...Maybe you should also add an answer detailing ALL the steps you took, for future readers.

Comment: No, I didn't run a cleaner—I don't trust them. As for detailing _all_ the steps I took, I'll see, but said steps were taken one or one-and-a-half at a time, and not documented by me as I took them, so I'll have to do a good bit of thinking (and speculating), to reconstruct something helpful.

Comment: *> there was a considerable difference between your registry key and mine, which you can see... my key on left, yours on the right*   @RobertThornton, actually, most of the "differences" were merely due to placement. If you sort the entries before diffing, then there will be much fewer differences, and most of those are configurable settings like update-frequency and preferred-server. The most notable difference is the DLL names, but I suspect that it is just a matter of env-var exapnsion (e.g., `%systemroot%` vs. `C:\Windows\`). You could probably have fixed it by re-registering the DLL(s).

Answer (score 0):

My computer is part of a Domain and the tab is not visible. If I disable the network card, then the tab can be seen/accessed. Re-enabling the NIC turns the tab invisible again.

Comment: Interesting. The catch of course is how to access the time server with no active card - or does any change persist once the card is re-enabled?